# Почему при указании в Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=hello.xls браузер отображает символы в окне, а не загружает как файл на диск?

Tags: http

Почему при указании в Responce Header Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=hello.xls браузер отображает данные в виде символов в окне, а не загружает как файл на диск?

Полный список:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Liferay-Portal: Liferay Community Edition Portal 7.2.0 CE GA1 (Mueller / Build 7200 / June 4, 2019)
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=hello.xls
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 19 Dec 2019 06:18:50 GMT
```

Comment: попробуйте `Content-Type: application/ms-excel`

Comment: не помогло. результат тот же

Comment: В смысле браузер открывает файл, а не предлагает сохранить? Какой браузер?

Comment: Вместо того, чтобы сохранить как файл на диске, в окне браузера выводятся иероглифы. Пробовал на Chrome, Firefox. Поправил вопрос и заголовок